# Populate Dropdown list using select, do post, and bean

Tags: jsp, html-select, auto-populate

Below is my doPost code:

```
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)        throws ServletException, IOException {
    //String Referer = request.getHeader("Referer") ; 
    //System.out.println("the refering page is " + Referer + " @ line 66of    producerController.doPost()"); 
    String url="";
    HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
    RequestDispatcher rd = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/isSessionNewController");
    rd.include(request, response);
    FieldmanFunctions fmf = new FieldmanFunctions();
    ArrayList prod_list = new ArrayList();
    prod_list = fmf.getProducerList(info.getPlant_ID());
    request.setAttribute("producer_list", prod_list);    // this sets the attribute(parm) to call array list by the JSP
    url=properties.getProperty("fieldman.page.template");
    System.out.println(prod_list.size() + " is the size of prod_list @ line 130 of fieldman controller");
    try{
            rd = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(url);
            rd.forward(request, response);
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e);
        }
}
```

Here is my Java method i am using to get the result set

```
    public ArrayList getProducerList(String Plant_ID){
    System.out.println("the following is the producer parm being passed in: "+Plant_ID+" @line 24 of FieldmanFunctions.getProducerTests ");
    ArrayList al = new ArrayList ();
    StringBuffer stmt = new StringBuffer();
    ResultFormBean rfb = new ResultFormBean(); // stmt = create a connection 
    stmt.append("call labapp.fieldman_pl('"+Plant_ID+"')");
    ResultSet rs = rfb.RS(stmt.toString()); 
    try{
        while (rs.next()){
            FieldmanListProducersBean flpb = new FieldmanListProducersBean();
            if(rs.getString("log_id4")!=null){
                flpb.setProducer_number(rs.getString("log_id4").trim());}
            if(rs.getString("name")!=null){
                flpb.setProducer_name(rs.getString("name").trim());}
            if(rs.getString("company_id")!=null){
                flpb.setCompany_id(rs.getString("company_id").trim());}

            al.add(flpb);
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    rfb.CloseConn(rs);
    return al;
}
```

Here is my bean code:

```
 public class FieldmanListProducersBean {
private String producer_number = "";
private String producer_name = "";
private String company_id = "";
private int producer_list_size =0;

public String getProducer_number() {
    return producer_number;
}
public void setProducer_number(String producer_number) {
    this.producer_number = producer_number;
}
public String getProducer_name() {
    return producer_name;
}
public void setProducer_name(String producer_name) {
    this.producer_name = producer_name;
}
public String getCompany_id() {
    return company_id;
}
public void setCompany_id(String company_id) {
    this.company_id = company_id;
}
public int getProducer_list_size() {
    return producer_list_size;
}
}
```

Here is my JSP page:

```
 <jsp:useBean id="UserInfo" class="com.dallasma.my.session.UserInfo" scope="session" />
 <%@taglib uri="/WEB-INF/app.tld" prefix="app" %>


<script type="text/javascript" src="/javascript/ajax_functions.js"></script>
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>  


<select name ="producer_list">
<option>producer_list</option>
<c:forEach var="pl" items="${producer_list}">
    <option value="${pl.LOG_ID4}">${pl}</option>
</c:forEach>
</select>

<table id="producer_list">
<tr id="header">
    <td>Producer Number</td>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td>Company ID</td>

</tr>
    <c:forEach items="${producer_list}" var="pt" varStatus="i">
        <c:set var="background_color" value="#fff"/>
        <c:set var="border_color" value="black"/>
        <c:set var="v" value=""/>
    <tr class="producer_list" id="<c:out value="${i.count}_row"/>"    style="border:1px solid black;display:block;">
        <td style="text-align:center;"><c:out         value="${pt.producer_number}"/></td>
        <td><c:out value="${pt.producer_name}"/></div></td>
        <td><c:out value="${pt.company_id}"/></div></td>
    </tr>
    </c:forEach>
 </table>
```

Here are my results... what am i doing wrong with the drop down list????
you will also see in the back ground of results.png that the table is populating fine.

[Results.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1AkPD.jpg)

## **FIXED **

was

`<option value="${pl.LOG_ID4}">${pl}</option>`

and is now below

`<option><c:out value="${pl.producer_number} - ${pl.producer_name}"></c:out> </option>`

This will show as "number - name"

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to show producer name in your select element.

If you want to use ${pl} to show the name, you need to override toString() method of `Object` class in your `Producer` class.
Otherwise, you would need to do this

```
<option value="${pl.producer_number}">${pl.producer_name}</option>
```

Comment: I have made the change you suggested and now the list shows `${pl.producer_name}` as opposed to:  `${pl}`   It is however returning the correct amount of rows.

Comment: I appreciate both the answer from Minjun and edit @naman it got me to compare why my table was working but not the drop down list. see updated post as to what fixed it!